# CameraCaptureTask completed event not firing in the ViewModel

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a simple application that has a single page with a button that invokes the CameraCaptureTask in Windows Phone 7. I use the MVVM pattern for this. My code behind is clean and I have offloaded the button click response to the ViewModel using behaviors. My code looks like this:

```
 public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly CameraCaptureTask cameraCaptureTask;

    /// <summary>
    ///   Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        if (IsInDesignMode)
        {
            // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
        }
        else
        {
            cameraCaptureTask = new CameraCaptureTask();
            cameraCaptureTask.Completed += cameraCaptureTask_Completed;
            CaptureCommand = new RelayCommand(() => CaptureImage());
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand CaptureCommand { get; set; }

    private void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e == null || e.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO
        }
    }

    private object CaptureImage()
    {
        cameraCaptureTask.Show();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now when I run my application and hit the button that binds to the 'CaptureCommand' RelayCommand, I hit my breakpoint in the 'CaptureCommand()' method and it fires the 'Show()' method of the CameraCaptureTask resulting in my camera coming up on the device successfully. However once I complete taking a picture and hit 'Accept', the 'cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, Photoresult e)' event handler never gets invoked. Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you relaying this when you have just a show?

Try moving the cameraCaptureTask out of the Constructor and into an invoked method

Comment: That did it thanks! I was just playing around with different ways of keeping the code behind as clean as possible. This might be a lame question but, is there a reason why the instantiation of that object in the ViewModel's constructor would not suffice?

Comment: I believe its because the camera isn't "loaded" yet. The UI/components aren't loaded/usable until the Loaded event gets fired

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the WPConnect tools when you do this with the debugger AND a device connected?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg180729(v=VS.92).aspx

> The Windows Phone Connect Tool allows you to establish serial or USB connectivity to the device without running the Zune software. When you test an application on a physical Windows Phone device, usually the Zune software is running. However, you are not able to test applications that interact with the photo chooser and camera launcher tasks while the Zune software is running, because it locks the local media database.

Comment: I did, but then I switched over to using the Emulator instead. That didn't work either.